# Web API actions

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

While not entirely RESTful, I think it makes sense to use actions where you're doing something more conceptually involved than just manipulating simple data.  Therefore I have adopted the following scheme:

```
/api/projects/ = Returns all projects
/api/projects/{id} = Returns single project

/api/projects/{id}/{action} [POST]
       Applies action on a project, such as "Activate"
/api/projects/{action} [GET]
       Gets projects which meet the condition of the action, such
       as all projects which are "Active"
```

But... Providing a way to get Projects for a Client is not so clear, I'm leaning towards option 2...

```
1. /api/projects/GetByClient [POST, Client Id in body]
       But now it has to be a POST, when we're only getting a resultset...
2. /api/clients/{clientid}/GetProjects
       But now we're returning projects from a clients controller
3. /api/ProjectGetterForClient/{client}
       But will result in a large number of URLs for a complex project
```

How should I go about making this kind of API available?

If #2 is the correct option.  Should I be returning just the list of Projects.  Or return the Client, which contains a list of Projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the most RESTful way would be:

```
GET: /api/clients/5/projects
```

This would return all projects for client with ID `5`.

You could also use:

```
GET: /api/projects?clientId=5
```

If your caller is likely to use project data whenever they request a client, then include it in the result. Otherwise you're better off keeping them as separate requests.

Comment: Your comment on the end about saying "if you're likely to use project data..." seems to be referring to calling '/api/clients/5' as always returning project data even if not explicitly requested.  What I was asking at the end of my question, is whether when using /api/clients/5/projects, should those projects come wrapped in a client object?  That way the client controller will still just be returning clients... I think not, as if you're calling that url you probably already have the client object's data. Just looking for confirmation...

Comment: If I called `/api/clients/5/projects` then I would expect the root objects in the result to be projects, not clients. You can actually have a request like this route to your projects controller, you just need to define the route before the default `api/{controller}/{id}`.

Comment: That's exactly what I had done - thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard about OData? It extends basic REST features and provides standardized format of queries.

For instance:

> Requesting an Individual Entity by ID
>
> The request below returns an individual entity of type Person by the
>   given UserName “russellwhyte”

```
GET serviceRoot/People('russellwhyte')
```

http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/

Or...

```
GET serviceRoot/Airports('KSFO')/Location/Address
```

In your case it could be I think more or less...

```
GET api/Clients('clientid')/Projects
```

As user1620220 mentioned - Web API has built-in support for OData: 
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options

Comment: Also note that Web API has [built-in support for OData](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options).

Comment: I was half-aware of OData, I didn't realise Web API had built-in support for it, however I think it's overkill for my scenario, I don't need (or want really) that level of customisation users can control.  I may still use it for sorting though, or basic filtering at a single level.  Thanks for the answer!